# Having sql connection open for a long time

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, database-connection

I'm writing a program that generates Sitemaps. To avoid duplicates I'm using MSSQL Server to store links that are found. during this process It may read and write millions of links and the process of reading and writing may have very little gaps between them (I mean the time between each access to database is very tiny).

I want to know If I can open the connection when the program starts and close it at the end. please consider that creating some sitemaps may take days to finish. Or is it wise to open and close connection each time I want to access the db?

By the way, I'm using sql server locally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question is the [Connection Pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8xx3tyca%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) feature.

It is always preferable to open the connection just when needed, access your data, close and dispose the connection immediately

Indeed a specific work pattern exists

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(.....))
{
   ... do your work with the database here ....
}
```

The [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) ensures that the object created at the opening is closed and disposed at the closing braces. **Even if an Exception occurs** in database code.

This doesn't mean that you cannot try to optimize your code. For example you could gather a few of sitemaps together and write them in just one shot, but usually it is best to follow a simple work pattern, finish the work as soon as possible and worry for optimization later.

Answer (score 0):

You can work with the following code :

```
SqlConnection conn;
try
{
    conn = new SqlConnection(_dbconnstr));
}
catch
{
    //exceptions are bubbled
    throw;
}
finally
{
    //Dispose is always called
    conn.Dispose();
}
```

hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I usually open and close connection each time I use it.
Releasing resources must be done when there is many connections around.
If you are the only one, you might keep your resources.
Be aware of setting timeout connection.

Good luck guy!

Comment: look at Steve's answer its great and I think you should use it too.

Comment: The question was if you should open and close the connection. Not how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to open/close the connection. There is no benefits in kipping connection open. [ADO.NET Connection pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx) (which is on by default) will take care of which connection to close and when.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca%28VS.71%29.aspx)

> CAUTION   It is recommended that you always close the Connection when
>   you are finished using it in order for the connection to be returned
>   to the pool. This can be done using either the Close or Dispose
>   methods of the Connection object. Connections that are not explicitly
>   closed might not be added or returned to the pool. For example, a
>   connection that has gone out of scope but that has not been explicitly
>   closed will only be returned to the connection pool if the maximum
>   pool size has been reached and the connection is still valid.

Answer (score 0):

If you know it's going to take a while, what about writing to a local data table and then when you reach a threshold, write all the records to the database.

Or even write the info to a local file (format of your choice) and then write that file to the database in one shot (or multiple shots if you want to do it every x records or y minutes.)